# Audio issue in After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I am learning after effects. I have got one template for after effect and trying to render it. all thing is working fine but just issue in audio output. I have selected audio output also in render but I am not getting audio, as well in preview ram. what I am missing ?[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is utterly off-topic. Check the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Audio is simply muted. Check speaker icon, must help

Answer (score 0):

Check your mute button or click RAM preview. Wait for video to render and click RAM preview button several times. I think it will solve the problem. I got this problem too but I clicked the RAM preview button and waited for it to render. And boom it worked.